# What's wrong with my code? "no such table: TaxiFile"

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite

here is the DBHelper class
       package com.example.taxirecordapp;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DBHelper(Context c, String dbName, int dbVer) {
        super(c, dbName, null, dbVer);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String driverSQL = "CREATE TABLE DriverFile (DriverNumber TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, DriverFName TEXT, DriverLName TEXT, DriverDateHired TEXT, DriverContactNumber TEXT, DriverAddress TEXT)";
        String taxiSQL = "CREATE TABLE TaxiFile (TaxiPlateNumber TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, TaxiDriverNumber TEXT, TaxiRentDate TEXT, TaxiDriverBalance INTEGER)";
        db.execSQL(taxiSQL);
        db.execSQL(driverSQL);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String driverSQL = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DriverFile";

        String taxiSQL = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TaxiFile";
        db.execSQL(taxiSQL);
        db.execSQL(driverSQL);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

the AddTaxi class

```
    package com.example.taxirecordapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AddTaxi extends Activity {

    EditText etPlateNumber, etDate, etBalance, etDriverNumber;
    Button btnSave, btnBack;
    SQLiteDatabase dbase;
    int position;
    int balance = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_taxi);

        DBHelper helper = new DBHelper(getApplication(), "TaxiRecordAppDB", 1);
        dbase = helper.getWritableDatabase();

        etPlateNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPlateNumber);
        etDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDate);
        etBalance = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etBalance);
        etDriverNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDriverNumber);
        btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        btnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBack);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        position = i.getIntExtra("position", position);

        Cursor rsCursor;
        String[] rsFields = { "DriverNumber", "DriverFName", "DriverLName",
                "DriverDateHired", "DriverContactNumber", "DriverAddress" };
        rsCursor = dbase.query("DriverFile", rsFields, null, null, null, null,
                null, null);
        rsCursor.moveToPosition(position);
        if (rsCursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
            if (rsCursor.getPosition() == position) {
                etDriverNumber.setText(rsCursor.getString(0).toString());
            }
        }
        rsCursor.close();

        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (etPlateNumber.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please input Plate Number!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();

                } else if (etDate.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please input Date Rented!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();

                }

                else {
                    if (etBalance.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                        balance = 0;

                    } else {
                        balance = Integer.parseInt(etBalance.getText()
                                .toString());
                    }
                    AddTaxiRecord(etPlateNumber.getText().toString(),
                            etDriverNumber.getText().toString(), etDate
                                    .getText().toString(), balance);
                }
            }
        });

        btnBack.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(AddTaxi.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }

    public void AddTaxiRecord(String plateNumber, String driverNumber,
            String date, int balance) {
        try {
            Cursor rsCursor;
            String[] rsFields = { "TaxiPlateNumber", "TaxiDriverNumber",
                    "TaxiRentDate", "TaxiDriverBalance" };
            rsCursor = dbase.query("TaxiFile", rsFields, "TaxiPlateNumber = "
                    + plateNumber, null, null, null, null, null);
            rsCursor.moveToFirst();
            if (rsCursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Plate number already exist!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                ContentValues rsValues = new ContentValues();
                rsValues.put("TaxiPlateNumber", plateNumber);
                rsValues.put("TaxiDriverNumber", driverNumber);
                rsValues.put("TaxiRentDate", date);
                rsValues.put("TaxiDriverBalance", balance);
                dbase.insert("TaxiFile", null, rsValues);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Record Successfully Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

}
```

and the AddDriver class which is working fine

```
    package com.example.taxirecordapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AddDriver extends Activity {

    EditText etDriverNumber, etFirstName, etLastName, etDateHired,
            etContactNumber, etAddress;
    Button btnSave, btnBack;
    SQLiteDatabase dbase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_driver);

        etDriverNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDriverNumber);
        etFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFirstName);
        etLastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etLastName);
        etDateHired = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDateHired);
        etContactNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etContactNumber);
        etAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAddress);
        btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        btnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBack);

        DBHelper helper = new DBHelper(getApplication(), "TaxiRecordAppDB", 1);
        dbase = helper.getWritableDatabase();

        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (etDriverNumber.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please input Driver Number!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();

                } else if (etFirstName.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please input Driver's First Name!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else if (etLastName.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please input Driver's Last Name!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else if (etDateHired.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please input Driver's Date Hired!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else if (etContactNumber.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please input Driver's Contact Number!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else if (etAddress.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please input Driver's Address!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                else {
                    AddDriverRecord(Integer.parseInt(etDriverNumber.getText()
                            .toString()), etFirstName.getText().toString(),
                            etLastName.getText().toString(), etDateHired
                                    .getText().toString(), etContactNumber
                                    .getText().toString(), etAddress.getText()
                                    .toString());
                }
            }
        });

        btnBack.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(AddDriver.this,
                        MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    public void AddDriverRecord(int driverNumber, String firstName,
            String lastName, String dateHired, String contactNumber,
            String address) {
        try {
            Cursor rsCursor;
            String[] rsFields = { "DriverNumber", "DriverFName", "DriverLName",
                    "DriverDateHired", "DriverContactNumber", "DriverAddress" };
            rsCursor = dbase.query("DriverFile", rsFields, "DriverNumber = "
                    + driverNumber, null, null, null, null, null);
            rsCursor.moveToFirst();
            if (rsCursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Driver number already exist!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                ContentValues rsValues = new ContentValues();
                rsValues.put("DriverNumber", driverNumber);
                rsValues.put("DriverFName", firstName);
                rsValues.put("DriverLName", lastName);
                rsValues.put("DriverDateHired", dateHired);
                rsValues.put("DriverContactNumber", contactNumber);
                rsValues.put("DriverAddress", address);
                dbase.insert("DriverFile", null, rsValues);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Record Successfully Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problems. So my guess is that you added the TaxiFile table after you added the DriverFile table.

To ensure that onUpgrade is called, you need to increase the database version but you are still using 1:

```
DBHelper helper = new DBHelper(getApplication(), "TaxiRecordAppDB", 1);
```

That probably means that TaxiFile is never created.

Every database schema change requires an increment of database version to make sure that onUpgrade is called.

Edit:

While development you can do the shortcut: Keep the version 1 but delete the app on the device or clear the data in the app info (both will force a complete new creation of the database).

Be warned: That shortcut does not work as soon as you have the app published because the user should never be required to do that. In that case you really need to handle schema changes and version increments by yourself.